# Bootstrap Datetimepicker for multiple inputs in the same input-group

Tags: input, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to use bootstrap datetimepicker with more than one input field within an input-group.

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group multi-input-group datetimepicker">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt fa-fw"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="formResidentRentStart">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt fa-fw"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="formResidentRentEnd">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-euro-sign fa-fw"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" name="formResidentRentRentValue">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to use datetimepicker for the first 2 inputs separately (they are not linked) and for the last input field not at all.

Is there anyone who achieved this already?

Thank you!

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0Lhq3w86/5/

Answer (score 0):

You should use Linked Pickers.

See : https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I would like to use my markup, linked pickers in the example are basically 2 separate input fields.